# Disabling table structure

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

I have a comprehensive web application with the use of lots of nested tables.
This app works fine for desktop version / view.

I am in the process of getting it setup for mobile view. Which is nearly done, BUT:

I am using JSP and java to, for example, retrieve search results. All of these are displayed in one row at a time. 
I am not able to make this row fit onto a mobile screen, so what I am looking for is a JavaScript function to disable the table structer, and just show the columns underneath each other e.g. - comparable with opera mini MOBILE VIEW, which with the click of a button makes contect fit to any screen size. My web app works fine, except of some tables, such as search results. I do not want to change the JSP, not create new pages - that would be too much work !

All I want is to include a certain JavaScript file if the connected user comes via handheld device (which works) and disable the tables, or make it fit properly to the screen !!

I hope someone is able to come up with a solution, I have tried everything with CSS, and few JavaScript bits (which I am not so familiar with)
I have two seperate CSS files, depending on the medium u conenct with, it chooses the right one.

BUT HOW TO GET RID OF THE TABLE OVERFLOW / that the data will be displayed fine, without having to scroll left and right on a small device, which as u know is very annoying ;) !?!?!?

Best regards
ALEX

Comment: Hence why using tables for layouts are a bad idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an alternative stylesheet:

```
tr{display:block;}
td{display:inline-block;}
```

...this should allow cells to float inside their parent row.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nu62m/

Comment: this is probably the answer. I checked IE7, doesn't work there, but most mobile browsers are based on WebKit, so should be fine, I think.

Comment: Yes, IE<=8 cannot figure it out, maybe IE9 will do, haven't tested it yet.